# Save new workbook from selected sheets

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

So my main goal is to save sheets (depending on if they are selected by a checkbox on the front page) to a new workbook.

I have 6 sheets, so I have 6 different checkboxes on my front page/sheet.

Here is my example code I've tried (Note: this only shows a check for 1 checkbox, however I require this for 6 checkboxes):

```
Sub saveSheetWorkbook()

Dim exampleName As Variant
Dim exampleSavePath As String
Dim exampleSheet As Variant

exampleName = InputBox("Who will this be sent to?")

exampleSavePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & exampleName

If Worksheets("Example Worksheet 1").Range("E29") = True Then
exampleSheet = "Example Worksheet 2"
End If

Sheets(Array("Example Worksheet 1"), exampleSheet).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=exampleSavePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

For example, I want to always save Example Worksheet 1, but only save Example Worksheet 2 (and 3,4,5,6) if the checkbox is ticked. The cell E29 in Example Worksheet 1 is the linked cell for the checkbox.

So this macro works when the checkbox is ticked, but when the checkbox is unticked, I get an error.

I have set it up so that the sheet array either contains the name or nothing. but when containing nothing, that gives me the error.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to act like follows (see comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub saveSheetWorkbook()
    Dim exampleSavePath As String
    Dim sheetsArr As Variant, linkedCellsArr As Variant
    Dim toBeCopiedSheetsNames As String
    Dim iElem As Long

    linkedCellsArr = Array("E29", "E30", "E31") '<--| list your linked cells addresses
    sheetsArr = Array("Example Worksheet 2", "Example Worksheet 3", "Example Worksheet 4") '<--| list your worksheets in corresponding order to linkedcells

    toBeCopiedSheetsNames = "Example Worksheet 1" '<--| put "Example Worksheet 1" worksheet in the worksheets to be copied list for sure
    For iElem = LBound(linkedCellsArr) To UBound(linkedCellsArr) '<--| loop through linked cells (addresses array)
        If Range(linkedCellsArr(iElem)) Then toBeCopiedSheetsNames = toBeCopiedSheetsNames & "|" & sheetsArr(iElem) '<-- if TRUE then add corresponding worksheet name to the worksheet to be copied list
    Next iElem

    exampleSavePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Application.InputBox("Who will this be sent to?", Type:=2) '<--| retrieve the file name and build its "full" name

    Sheets(Split(toBeCopiedSheetsNames, "|")).Copy '<--| copy worksheets whose name is listed in 'toBeCopiedSheetsNames'
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=exampleSavePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: @DisplayName, did you get through it?

Comment: Thanks! Will test it in a day or two when I get back to my PC and update this question.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work when I try it. I get a "Subscript out of range" error on this line: Sheets(Split(toBeCopiedSheetsNames, "|")).Copy.

Comment: You must step through your code and query relevant variables values in the immediate window. For instance you could type "?toBeCopiedSheetsNames", press return and check there are all valid worksheet names separated by "|"

Comment: Thank you, one of my sheet names was incorrect. Very sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
If Worksheets("Example Worksheet 1").Range("E29") = True Then
    exampleSheet = "Example Worksheet 2"
End If
Sheets(Array("Example Worksheet 1"), exampleSheet).Copy
```

With this:

```
If Worksheets("Example Worksheet 1").Range("E29") = True Then
    exampleSheet = "Example Worksheet 2"
    Sheets(Array("Example Worksheet 1", exampleSheet)).Copy
Else
    Sheets("Example Worksheet 1").Copy
End If
```